# how to create optgroup with laravel collective?

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

I need to create a `optgroupt` with **laravel collective**.

Below is my current code:

```
<select id="cmb" name="cmb">
   <option></option>
   @foreach($sedeCaptura as $i)
      <optgroup label="SEDE - {{ $i["SedeCaptura"] }}">
         <option value="{!! $i["SedeCaptura"] !!}" >
            {!! $i["IdField"].' - '.$i["DescriptionField"].' - ('.$i["TotalField"].')' !!}
         </option>
      </optgroup>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

How do I recreate this code with laravel collective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple multidimensional array should do the job
as specified in the [documentation](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#drop-down-lists) you can pass a key for the label and an array of key => value pair as follow:

```
echo Form::select('animal',[
    'Cats' => ['leopard' => 'Leopard'],
    'Dogs' => ['spaniel' => 'Spaniel'],
]);
```